# Python:Need to extract specific column and its values and to save it to a text file in python

Tags: python

I need to extract the values of a coloumn "VON MISES" in a text file and want to extract the values below that coloumn name.I tried splitting the column but couldnt make upto the result.I am new to python.Please help me.Thanks in advance.I am copying the part of my text file upon which i have to work.I need the last column values as answer

```
# open file
f = open ("new.txt","r")

#Read whole file into data
data = f.read()

# Print it
print data
line_number=1
for num,line in enumerate(open("new.txt")):
        if "VON MISES" in line:
            print num+1
f.close()
```

Comment: Please can you a) cut this right down so it contains a *small* representative sample of your data and b) show what you have tried so far. You can probably just do this with the pandas or csv libraries though.

Answer (score 0):

you could try pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("new.txt", sep=',')
v_m = df['VON MISES']

out_file = open("out.txt", "w")
v_m.to_csv(out_file)
```